# What is a JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to understand what `JSON` schema is. I understand its related to `JSON`. But what is it used for? How does one create a schema? Can any `JSON` be a `JSON` schema?

Comment: Here are some resources.  http://json-schema.org/ http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/

Answer (score 1):

[JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) describes your JSON data format, for sample, the general structure of a json content if the schema, for sample:

```
{
    "title": "Example Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        }
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

You have a property called `title` which is a `string`, you have a property called `properties` which is an `object` with other properties.

### See more

http://json-schema.org/examples.html